# solr: How to specify precisionStep in lucene query syntax

Tags: solr, lucene

From the NumericRangeQuery docs (http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html#precisionStepDesc):

> "...Because of this, the ideal precisionStep value can only be found
>   out by testing. Important: You can index with a lower precision step
>   value and test search speed using a multiple of the original step
>   value."

Is it possible to specify the "precisionStep" parameter in the lucene query syntax? I have a query like this:

mod_date:[* TO 20030101]

And would like to find the optimal precisionStep value. My plan is to set precisionStep to 1 in the schema definition, then testing the performance with other values, as described in the docs. However, I only found a way to specify the precisionStep value in the Java query classes, not in the query syntax.